# How to install android from my Computer terminal?

Tags: adb, installation, fastboot, terminal, operating-system

I have a HTC M7 without any OS on it (it goes to black screen when I boot it).

It doesn't have any memory card.

I am however able to have a root shell with "adb shell" when connecting it with USB.

How can I reinstall android from my computer?

Comment: Something called "RUU" - go look it up. I don't have time for a complete answer right now...

Answer (score 0):

You can boot into the bootloader and flash the phone with a RUU file from [here](http://androidruu.com) or from [here](http://www.htc1guru.com/downloads/ruu-file-downloads/). Download the one suitable for your CID (Carrier ID).

```
adb reboot-bootloader
```